# Pythonic use of timeout decorator with variable timeout

Tags: python, timeout, decorator

I have a routine that needs to call a number of other functions, and apply a timeout to those functions. I am using the timeout_decorator package. Assume I have a global variable "timeout" with default 120 (seconds). I need to be able to override this on a case by case basis via a command-line argument.

It appears to me that simple use of the decorator does not provide the override option. E.g.

```
@timeout_decorator.timeout(timeout)
def my_function_not_allowed_to_run_too_long(stuff):
    etc...
```

will have the default value of timeout, which can't be overridden as the decorator is evaluated prior to processing the command line.

I implemented the following:

```
class CallFuncWithTimeout(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    @timeout_decorator.timeout(timeout)
    def doit(self, *args, **kwargs):
        res = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        return res
```

which can be called as follows:

```
my_func = CallFuncWithTimeout(my_function_not_allowed_to_run_too_long)
try:
    res = my_func.doit(stuff)
except timeout_decorator.timeout_decorator.TimeoutError:
    # handle timeout...
```

It appears to work; I assume because the class is not instantiated until after the command line has been processed and thus the "timeout" variable in the class reflects the command line value.

My question: is this the cleanest way to get this functionality? Am I missing something easier?

Comment: Timeouts are something that I think are better handled by context managers rather than decorators. `with Timeout(however_long_you_like): my_function(stuff)`.

Answer (score 0):

`@timeout_decorator` adds a `timeout` argument to the decorated function. Pass a `timeout` argument while calling the function: `my_function_not_allowed_to_run_too_long(timeout=<variable_timeout>)` to override the default one.